# Injecting into EJBs

Tags: glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi

I am trying to convert a Guice inject project to a Java EE project, that is to run on glassfish.

I have a lib project, that defines an interface, Hello, annotated with `@Remote`. Then I have an impl project that has a bean, `HelloBean`, annotated with `@Stateless`, and a single constructor with parameters and `@Inject`.

Then I have a was project that depends on the lib and it's interface to create a webservice, `HelloService`, annotated with `@WebService`, and `Hello` as a member annotated with `@EJB`.

This does not seem to work. Since beans must have a no-args constructor, I created `HelloBean` as a bean, and `HelloImpl` as a Pojo with a single `@Inject` constructor, with arguments. I have tried then injecting `Hello` and `HelloImpl` into `HelloBean` with both `@Inject`, `@Resource` and `@EJB`. None seem to work.

If I `@Inject` `Hello` or `HelloImpl` into `HelloBean`, I get a NPE.
If I `@Resource` `Hello` or `HelloImpl`, I get an `Lookup failed for delegate`.
If I `@EJB` `HelloImpl`, same error. `@EJB` `Hello` and I get stackoverflows (understandably).

I do want to use constructor injection, as I feel it's a more correct way of creating classes (they are always valid once constructed). But I don't see how it's possible to combine CDI and EJBs.

How can I get a Pojo with an `@Inject` constructor into a bean? Or is my plan fundamentally flawed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Glassfish 4.1 can't run RestFul service when using ear/ejb/web module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879898/glassfish-4-1-cant-run-restful-service-when-using-ear-ejb-web-module)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way is to define a initialize method annotated with @Inject. Any parameters will be injection points and should be supplied via CDI. You can also do this with constructors. Make sure you have WEB-INF/beans.xml as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the beans.xml file.