# MultiException when try to inject EJB into REST

Tags: java, rest, ejb, cdi

When i try to inject an EJB into my REST service, i get a MultiException, i can't understand why this happen.

**Edit** I'm using WildFly 8.2.0 and Jersey 2.17

**EJB**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class UserServiceBean<T> implements UserService<T> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="UC-ServerPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public T create(T t) {
        em.persist(t);
        em.flush();
        return t;
    }
    @Override
    public T find(Class type, Object id) {
        return (T) em.find(type, id);
    }
    @Override
    public T update(T t) {
        em.persist(t);
        em.flush();
        return t;
    }
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll(String namedQuery) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
        List<T> all = query.getResultList();
        return all;
    }
    @Override
    public T remove(Class type, Object id) {
        T t = (T) em.find(type, id);
        em.remove(t);
        return t;
    }

}
```

**REST**

```
@Stateless
@Path("/users")
public class UserServiceFacade {   
    @Inject
    private UserServiceBean<User> userCrudService;

    @POST
    @Path("/save")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void save(String strJson) {
        System.out.println("UserDao is null? "+userCrudService == null);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strJson);
        User user = UserUtil.buildUser(json.getJSONArray("user"));
    }
    @PUT
    @Path("/update")
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public void update(JSONObject user) {

    }
    @DELETE
    @Path("/remove/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathParam("id") Short id) {

    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Path("/all")
    public String findAll() {
        System.out.println("Recuperar todos!");
        return "<p>Accediendo a todos los usuarios...</p>";
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/find/{id}")
    public void find(@PathParam("id") Short id) {

    }

}
```

If i type i try to access to some path, this exception is raised:

```
22:34:38,007 WARNING [org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors] (default task-2) The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
MultiException stack 1 of 3
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=UserServiceBean,parent=UserServiceFacade,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,7621135)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:237)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.company.userscontrol.rest.UserServiceFacade errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 3 of 3
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.company.userscontrol.rest.UserServiceFacade
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:389)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


22:34:38,070 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /UC-Server/api/users/all: javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=UserServiceBean,parent=UserServiceFacade,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,7621135)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.company.userscontrol.rest.UserServiceFacade errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.company.userscontrol.rest.UserServiceFacade

    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:421) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:222) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=UserServiceBean,parent=UserServiceFacade,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,7621135)
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.company.userscontrol.rest.UserServiceFacade errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.company.userscontrol.rest.UserServiceFacade

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:88) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:252) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:360) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:297) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110) [jersey-server.jar:]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:401) [jersey-container-servlet-core.jar:]
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=UserServiceBean,parent=UserServiceFacade,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,7621135)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:237) [hk2-locator-2.4.0-b10.jar:]
    ... 56 more
```

The response code is 500, internal server error.

I'm doing something wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try to change javax.ejb.Stateless to javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped on UserServiceFacade? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879898/glassfish-4-1-cant-run-restful-service-when-using-ear-ejb-web-module

Answer (score 2):

When working with WildFly, you should really use the built-in JAX-RS implementation RESTEasy instead of Jersey.

I'm not sure if it is possible at all to override RESTEasy by an alternative implementation included in your WAR or EAR - even in the best case, this is bound to require additional configuration.

Moreover, your stacktrace includes `org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver`, which indicates that `@Inject` is not handled by CDI at all, but by another JSR-330 implementation used by GlassFish/Jersey internally. An additional library may be required for [CDI support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/cdi.support.html), but as I said, this might cause conflicts on WildFly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll re-create the project and now works fine (In GlassFish and WildFly ;))